# @Watch decorator not activating

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've got a simple Test component, the template looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="name" class="form-control">
    <h5>{{ message }}</h5>
  </div>
</template>
<script src="./test.ts" lang="ts"></script>
```

and the component TypeScript looks like this:

```
declare var Vue: typeof Function;
declare var VueClassComponent: any;

import { Component, Inject, Model, Prop, Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";

@VueClassComponent.default({
  template: require("./test.vue"),
  style: require("./test.sass"),
  props: {
    name: String,
    num: Number
  }
})
export default class TestComponent extends Vue {
  name: string;
  num: number;
  message: string = "";

  @Watch("name")
  protected onNameChanged(newName: string, oldName: string): any {
    console.log("setting " + oldName + " to " + newName);
  }

  mounted(this: any): void {
    console.log("mounted called");
    this.message = "Hello " + this.name + " " + this.num;
  }
}
```

When I type in the `input` box, the @Watch("name") handler never fires, however I do get these errors in the `console`:

```
[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "name"
```

Once for every character entered in the `input` box. I have no idea where the name is being set, because I have not set it anywhere. Although that is my goal (to update name) I've been reading you can't just change the value directly, you need to set @Watch handlers, and then somewhere else set them (I still don't understand exactly *how* but can't even get that for right now.

Comment: The warning is because you have `name` as a property, and you set `v-model="name"` on your input, thus, attempting to mutate the prop.

Comment: @BertEvans That was my guess as well, but this is how the examples show it. What would you suggest?

Comment: What example? I expect what you want to do is use this like `<test-component v-model="name"></test-component>` somewhere?

Comment: @BertEvans This is the example: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Comment: @BertEvans This is a property within a component, I'm confused by the suggestion to place this in the html tag for the component as a whole, rather than the input field that the property is attached to. (It should always represent the `name` as it changes).

Comment: What I mean is, if this is a component, you typically want to use what is input *outside* the component somewhere. Is the thing you want to share with the *parent* the name?

Comment: @BertEvans well, in this case it's a simple "Type in a name and get a hello {{name}} message back" just as a small functioning test. In the future I will be adding components which get *all* of their data from an outside source, but even this simple attempt at a self-contained component seems extremely complicated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139388/discussion-between-bert-evans-and-nick-jennings).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on our discussion, the root of the problem here was declaring `name` as a property. The intention was that `name` was an internal value that would simply be used to derive `message`. That being the case, a watch is unnecessary and a computed does the trick.

```
declare var Vue: typeof Function;
declare var VueClassComponent: any;

import { Component, Inject, Model, Prop, Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";

@VueClassComponent.default({
  template: require("./test.vue"),
  style: require("./test.sass"),
  props: {
    num: Number
  }
})
export default class TestComponent extends Vue {
  name: string;
  num: number;

  get message(){
      return "Hello " + this.name + " " + this.num;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was because the name variable is not initialised and so does not yet exist on 'this'. If it was initialised with any value then a proxyGetter would have been created for it and the watch would work.

For Vue 2 this is described here [enter link description here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)